# Search button besides a heading using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've seen this functionality on the appBar before, but I need to create it outside the appBar. Here is an illustration of it:

[drawing of the funcionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqS0u.png)

The idea is to have a Heading on the left side of the row and on the right side a button with a magnifying glass that once clicked opens to the left covering the Heading.

This what I currently have:

[current state - two lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqS0u.png)

I was thinking on having a Stack with the two of them and positioning the button to the left animating the TextField to the right when clicking it.

Stack( children: [ _title(context: context), _searchField(context: context), ], ),

Comment: You have posted the same image twice

Comment: I thought the previous one wasn't approved. It asked me to improve the question. Its status is "Closed".